# Do the following alternating series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have $3$ alternating series as

1. $2-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{4}{3}-\frac{5}{4}+\cdots$=$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{n+1}{n}$
2. $\frac{1}{\log 2}-\frac{1}{\log 3}+\frac{1}{\log 4}-\frac{1}{\log 5}\cdots$
3. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+1}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}+1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}+1}-\cdots$

Now I applied Alternating series test(AST) to $(2)$ and found that it is convergent. For $(1)$ we cannot apply the AST as the $n$-th term does not goes to zero? But it seems convergent to me. I am clueless about the $(3)$.

Am I correct with my conclusions? What results should I apply to $2$ and $3$? Any hints please.

Comment: For $(1)$, what is a necessary condition for convergence? For $(3)$, just apply the AST.

Comment: Please explain in detail why (1) seems convergent to you.

Comment: Actually I am not sure but absolute value of the $n$-th term goes to $1$ perhaps lead me to think it is convergent. Can you shade more light on it @Did

Comment: Let us simplify the situation as much as we can: do you think $\sum\limits_n(-1)^n$ converges "because the absolute value of the $n$th term goes to $1$"? *After you decided for yourself what you think*, try to remember the definition of the convergence of a series $\sum\limits_nx_n$.

Comment: Yes I got it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to (2), you are right that the alternating series test says it converges.

The $n$-th term does not converge to $0$ (it doesn't even converge, period.) in 1, so, no convergence. In any series (alternating or not), if it converges , then $a_n$ tends to $0$.

In (3) the AST also works.

Answer (score 3):

The series $\sum a_n$ is divergent if $(a_n)$ hasn't the limit $0$. So the series in 1. is divergent.

For 3.the sequence $\frac{1}{\sqrt n+1}$ is decreasing and has the limit $0$ so you can apply AST.

Answer (score 2):

You can say more for 1):

Set $\displaystyle s_2n=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{k+1}k $. Grouping pairs of consecutive terms, you can write
$$s_{2n}=\sum_{i=1}^n\biggl(\frac{2i}{2i-1}-\frac{2i+1}{2i}\biggr)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{2i(2i-1)}=\sum_{i=1}^n\biggl(\frac{1}{2i-1}-\frac{1}{2i}\biggr)=\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k},$$
so $\;s_{2n}$ corresponds to the *alternating harmonic series*, which converges to $\color{red}{\ln 2}$.

As $\;s_{2n+1}=s_{2n}+\dfrac{2n+2}{2n+1}$, we see the sums of an odd number of terms also converge, to $\color{red}{\ln 2+1}$.

Comment: But $1$ is divergent right?

Comment: Absolutely,. In only say the sum of an odd number of termes is just the sum of an even number of terms, plus osmething which tends to $1$. Hen=cer the sequence of partial sums  has $2$ subsequences which converge to $ln 2$ and $\ln 2+1$ respectively. So it says a little more than the mere ‘the given series diverges’, since we know partial sums are bounded.

Comment: yes absolutely. thanks to show this aspect too.